# Creating for a Docker Secure Registry

Tags: docker

I'm trying to setup a private Docker registry. However, I getting errors.

## Here is the complete CODE

mkdir certs
mkdir auth

vi /etc/hosts     # Making an entry for myregistrydomain.com

sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000

su -

cd /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/

cp /home/cloud_user/certs/dockerrepo.crt ca.crt

exit

docker images

docker pull registry:2

docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn test password > auth/htpasswd

cd auth

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/dockerrepo.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/dockerrepo.key -v `pwd`/auth:/auth -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM="Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd registry:2

docker pull busybox

docker tag busybox myregistrydomain.com:5000/my-busybox         #

docker login myregistrydomain.com:5000/my-busybox

I received error

I ran the following command, but it gave an error:

docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn test password > auth/htpasswd

I, then ran the command with -B flag, but receives an error again

docker run --entrypoint  htpasswd registry:2 -B test password > auth/htpasswd

htpasswd: cannot modify file test; use '-c' to create it

Tried the command with -c flag, but still same error

docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -B test password > auth/htpasswd -c

The SHA algorithm does not use a salt and is less secure than the MD5 algorithm.

I cat auth/htpasswd, no password is generated.

## Getting an error

Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistrydomain.com:5000/v2/: dial tcp 172.31.38.31:5000: connect: connection refused

Comment: Are you sure your hosts is correct? Try set it to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but error again "Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://myregistrydomain.com:5000/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized"

Comment: Can you please try run with `-Bbn` and without `-c` again? On my server it created the password file just file. It should be what you are looking for. I believe it will work fine now. If it still gives an error, please tell us what it is.

Comment: Thanks, it did create a password file in auth directory. However, I get a 401 Unauthorized error. I tried curl -k <IP_address>:5000, and I received connection refused error. Someone suggested to append a line: 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// –insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:5000' at botthom of: /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, and that didn't work either

Comment: Did you add the Authorization header?

Comment: Probably not, don't know how to add Authorization header